# Как создать плавный скрол при передвижении мыши?

Tags: javascript

В общем задача такова: нужно при передвижении мыши с зажатой левой кнопкой скролить страницу (куда передвигаем туда и скролим).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну на вскидку я себе это представляю так: при нажатии мыши (onMouseDown) брать координаты относительно верха окна браузера. Проверять, нажата ли клавиша мыши (onMouseDown, onMouseUp) при движении (onMouseMove), и если да, то получать текущие координаты, вычитать разницу (она больше или меньше) и скролировать (scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset ± dOffset)).

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так: ширина окна - 100%, потом пропорцией считал, где курсор и скролил туда.
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LZ7Eq/